# Unable to gunzip fastq files from ENA

Tags: fastq, gene-expression

I am trying to process fastq files in order to build gene co-expression networks (by following [this tutorial](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29525965)). When I download any fastq file from ENA, and try to process it with the command:
`ls *.fastq.gz | xargs -n1 fastqc $1`, I get:

```
Failed to process SRR494099.fastq.gz
java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:269)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:259)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:92)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Utilities.MultiMemberGZIPInputStream.<init>(MultiMemberGZIPInputStream.java:37)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.FastQFile.<init>(FastQFile.java:80)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.SequenceFactory.getSequenceFile(SequenceFactory.java:106)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.SequenceFactory.getSequenceFile(SequenceFactory.java:62)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.OfflineRunner.processFile(OfflineRunner.java:159)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.OfflineRunner.<init>(OfflineRunner.java:121)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.FastQCApplication.main(FastQCApplication.java:316)
```

Similarly, when I just download the fastq files and try to decompress them using gunzip, I get, for example: `gzip: SRR494099.fastq.gz: unexpected end of file`
Why is this happening?

Comment: Likely that your fastq file is not successfully download based on `unexpected end of file`. Try `zcat SRR494099.fastq.gz | tail`

Comment: @PhoenixMu I get `gzip: SRR494099.fastq.gz: unexpected end of file` when I do this

Comment: fastqc by the way does read gzipped files, no need for decompression.

Comment: @ATpoint yeah I was just trying to see if the problem was with fastqc or with the file itself. But none of the files that I download from ENA are working

Comment: do they provide file hashes such as e.g. checksums that you can use to ensure that nothing weird happened to the files?

Comment: @MaximilianPress no but it doesn't just happen with the files I'm interested in. Any fastq file.

Comment: I just downloaded SRR494099 with the download link from sra-explorer.info and it runs fine with fastqc. Something seems to wrong with your downloads. I suggest yu download via Aspera (https://www.biostars.org/p/325010/) since this will only create the final file if download finished successfully.

Comment: Hm, that is difficult. If you can't verify the integrity of your files it will be hard to say what the issue is- but it's almost certain that they are messed up somehow. I'd follow ATpoint's suggestion or other alternative means of downloading. Possibly also switching to a clean environment with robust networking such as a fresh node on a HPC cluster might clear something up with your downloads.